# Openvpn script on (re)connect?

Tags: openvpn

Openvpn can execute a script upon connection using the --up parameter. However this does not seem to work at *re*connecting, i.e. when a connection is lost and openvpn automatically reconnects. Is this normal behaviour and is there a way to execute scripts on reconnect too?

Background is that there is a service that supposed to communicate over a VPN. If the connection gets lost, the service might timeout and quit. Therefore I want to have a script running on VPN-connection, that checks if the service is running and if not, starting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *normal behavior*. By default, OpenVPN does not run the `--up script` for *partial restarts* (In your case: reconnects) .  You can change this behavior by using the `--up-restart` option in your client config.
This is clearly documented in the [OpenVPN Manual](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/manuals.html)

Comment: @Jherek did you try this ?

Comment: I did something with a cron job as a workaround. But thanks for your answer anyhow. When I have time I will look into it again.